# Deploying Flask App with Multiple Routes on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, deployment

I have followed this guide to deploy flask app on EC2:

https://aws.plainenglish.io/deploying-a-flask-application-on-ec2-54cfeb396fa1

It works fine for the main page "/" but for other routes that I created it shows 404 error. It seems there is some configuration error that I need to adjust to accommodate other routes but I am unable to do so. Can any one help me out?

Comment: Share the code you are using, or parts of it, so people can understand it and help you better.

Comment: It's exactly the same as in the link with an extra route